# Installed Module is not found in VsCode Import: No module named "numpy" / "cv2" [python]

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I was working on some motion detection python scripts using numpy and open cv on Visual Studio Code, all the imports were working correctly.
I installed the Platform IO extension for VScode as well as some python extensions (linter, intellisense..) and none of my imports work anymore (though numpy and open cv have correctly been installed, see picture). 
I tried desinstalling numpy and open cv, re-installing, re-installing through anaconda, un-installing the extensions and re-booting, but nothing seems to work.

Do any of you know what I could try now?

Thanks!

Numpy module is detected but not imported:
[image: img]

Comment: Have you checked that the correct python interpreter is being used?

Comment: Yep I have tried with all 4 python versions I have installed (which were previously installed as well: 3.6.4,3.6.5,3.7.3,3.7.4 and nothing changed

Comment: make sure you installed in the correct python virtual environment. you should use the same python virtual environment in VS code as well. please read more here [VS Code Python Environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)